# Disable control for a single page when the control runs from masterpase in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am designing a website  for avoid the code complexity i use controls for footer section and i call the control in master page itself. but now my client asks they not need footer for a particular page named contactus.

so, here any programmatic way to disable the control for a single page or any other solutions available?

my master page structure:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="bodywrapper">
            <ucdart:Header ID="Header1" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <ucdart:Footer ID="Footer1" runat="server" />
</from>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Control c = Master.FindControl("Footer1");
 c.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this on the page you want to hide the div

```
Footer  foot = (Footer)Master.FindControl("Footer1");
foot.Visible = false;
```

and this on a page you want to show the div

```
Footer  foot = (Footer)Master.FindControl("Footer1");
foot.Visible = true;
```

Comment: its works with the code `Control c = Master.FindControl("Footer1");
            c.Visible = false;` thank you for guide me on a point :)